# Terminal - run 'file' (file type) for the whole directory

Tags: bash, file, types, terminal

I'm a beginner in the terminal and bash language, so please be gentle and answer thoroughly. :)

I'm using Cygwin terminal.

I'm using the **file** command, which returns the file type, like:

```
$ file myfile1
myfile1: HTML document, ASCII text
```

Now, I have a directory called *test*, and I want to check the type of all files in it.

**My endeavors:**

I checked in the **man page** for file (*man file*), and I could see in the examples that you could type the names of all files after the command and it gives the types of all, like:

```
$ file myfile{1,2,3}
myfile1: HTML document, ASCII text
myfile2: gzip compressed data
myfile3: HTML document, ASCII text
```

But my files' names are random, so there's no specific pattern to follow.
I tried using the **for** loop, which I think is going to be the answer, but this didn't work:

```
$ for f in ls; do file $f; done
ls: cannot open `ls' (No such file or directory)

$ for f in ./; do file $f; done
./: directory
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just use a glob that matches every file. `file *`

Comment: @EtanReisner That was too simple! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Unix or Linux shell supports some kind of globs. In your case, all you need is to use `*` glob. This magic symbol represents all folders and files in the given path.

eg., `file directory/*`

Shell will substitute the glob with all matching files and directories in the given path. The resulting command that will actually get executed might be something like:

`file directory/foo directory/bar directory/baz`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of the `find` and `xargs` command.

For example:

```
find /your/directory/ | xargs file
```

HTH

Comment: Wildly excessive for this need. Even if the directory structure is more than one level deep.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Though @EtanReisner gave a shorter solution: `file *`

Comment: This benefit of this solution is that it recurses directories, so could be useful for that use case.

Answer (score 1):

```
file directory/*
```

Is probably the shortest simplest solution to fix your issue, but this is more of an answer as to why your loops weren't working.

```
for f in ls; do file $f; done
ls: cannot open `ls' (No such file or directory)
```

For this loop it is saying "for f in the directory or file 'ls' ; do..." If you wanted it to execute the `ls` command then you would need to do something like this

```
for f in `ls`; do file "$f"; done
```

But that wouldn't work correctly if any of the filenames contain whitespace. It is safer and more efficient to use the shell's builtin "globbing" like this

```
for f in *; do file "$f"; done
```

For this one there's an easy fix.

```
for f in ./; do file $f; done
./: directory
```

Currently, you're asking it to run the file command for the directory "./".
By changing it to " ./* " meaning, everything within the current directory (which is the same thing as just *).

```
for f in ./*; do file "$f"; done
```

Remember, double quote variables to prevent globbing and word splitting.

https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086

Comment: Dave, there was no need to change my answer. The code that you changed was OP's code and my explanation as to why it wouldn't work, followed by a solution.